# Installed nvidia 331, error in steam

Tags: nvidia, steam

I've installed correctly the nvidia 331 drivers in my ubuntu 64bit, but when i open a game in steam i see this error: Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glColorMaskIndexedEXT' nvidia 331

Any solutions?

Comment: What procedure did you follow in order to install 331 ?

Comment: What is your graphics card? It is possible there are some incompatabilities with Nvidia 331 that we need to know about.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. I installed the 331 driver via the xorg-edgers PPA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenGL problems with steam](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530798/opengl-problems-with-steam)