# OpenGL problems with steam

Tags: steam, opengl, gpu-driver

Any time i launch a source game on steam i get the message

> Could not find required OpenGL entry pint 'glGetError'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated

UPDATE: I updated my intel graphics drivers and now i'm getting a different error

> Could not find required OpenGL entry point 'glColorMaskIndexedEXT'! Either your video card is unsupported, or your OpenGL driver needs to be updated.

Comment: Welcome to AU! What kind of graphics adapter do you have? Its driver probably doesn't support the OpenGL version or extension required for the Source game engine. Can you [include](https://askubuntu.com/posts/530798/edit) the output of `glxinfo` in your question please?

Comment: here. http://pastebin.com/b5VMmYpF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glColorMaskIndexedEXT` is part of the OpenGL extension [`EXT_draw_buffers2`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/draw_buffers2.txt), which is unsupported by your graphics adapter (at least with the current driver) according to the [output of `glxinfo`](http://pastebin.com/b5VMmYpF) you provided.

You are very likely unable to launch Source engine based games under Linux with your current hardware.