# Could not find required OpenGL entry pint 'glGetError'! fix?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, games, steam

So I know this is kind of beating a dead horse right now but I realized that most of the solutions to this problem are by all means outdated due to the file structure changes that steam has gone through.  What I'm wondering if possible is for the best working solution to get this to work.  I have two computers, one for high performance gaming and a toughbook cf-19 1ghz 32 bit laptop with 4gb of ram with a mesa dri intel 945 gm x86/mmx/sse2 gpu for schoolwork and low spec gaming.  As a test I wanted to try and play half life 2 and use some conf modifications to test the game at its lowest resolution.  Anyways any help would be awesome.  Thanks and regards :)

Comment: May be related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/530798/opengl-problems-with-steam